# JS split, keep delimiter minus its first character

Tags: javascript

**Original, string:** `"FOO,blue,FOO,yellow,red,FOO,purple,brown,blue,FOOred,orange,FOO,blue,yellow"`

I'd like to convert this mixed string to an array, splitting specifically at each `,FOO`, and keep `FOO`.

**Code:**

```
var str = "blue,FOO,yellow,red,FOO,purple,brown,blue,FOOred,orange,FOO,blue,yellow"
var regex = /(?=,FOO)/g
console.log(str.split(regex))
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/MWvgxMM)

**Desired result:**

```
[
'FOO,blue',
'FOO,yellow,red',
'FOO,purple,brown,blue',
'FOOred,orange',
'FOO,blue,yellow',
]
```

**Current result:**

```
[
'FOO,blue',
',FOO,yellow,red',
',FOO,purple,brown,blue',
',FOOred,orange',
',FOO,blue,yellow',
]
```

As you see, each `FOO` instance included the preceding comma; how can I exclude the comma in the same regex operation?

```js
    var str = "FOO,blue,FOO,yellow,red,FOO,purple,brown,blue,FOOred,orange,FOO,blue,yellow"
    var regex = /(?=,FOO)/g
    console.log(str.split(regex))
```

Comment: Do you want the `FOO,` on the `blue` one? Since `FOO,` doesn't exist in the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only looking ahead for the comma at the moment - you need to include it in the match (outside of the lookahead) for it to be split upon and not included in the result.

```js
var str = "FOO,blue,FOO,yellow,red,FOO,purple,brown,blue,FOOred,orange,FOO,blue,yellow"
var regex = /,(?=FOO)/g
console.log(str.split(regex))
```